# Multidimensional array in Swift 2.2 removeAtIndex

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have anything like that

```
array = self.rescataRegistroFav()

rescataRegistroFav(){

return (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("MIARRAYFAV"))!

}
```

I want remove ["DEF", "56", "78"], how can I do? Can't use removeAtIndex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `removeAtIndex`:

```
var array = [["ABC", "12", "34"],["DEF", "56", "78"],["GHI", "90", "01"]]
array.removeAtIndex(1)
```

**Edit:**
With the given information in the comments:
`NSArray` is not mutable. You can make your `rescataRegistrosFav` function return an `NSMutableArray` and then do the following:

```
array.removeObjectAtIndex(1)
```

IF you want your current code to work you could make your `rescataRegistrosFav` function return a `[[String]]` and then do

```
array.removeAtIndex(1)
```

I prefere the `NSMutableArray` though.

Comment: Value of type 'NSArray' has no member 'removeAtIndex'

Comment: I use this "var array = self.rescataRegistrosFav()", RescataRegistrosFav() is a method to return array from "NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("MIARRAYFAV"))!"

Comment: In "rescataRegistrosFav" I try to do this:

 let devuelve = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("MIARRAYFAV")!

return devuelve as NSMutableArray

But "Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to specified type NSMutableArray"